# MongoDB/PyMongo: Querying multiple criteria - unexpected results

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, querying

I have a collection where some of the objects feature an key `foo`. I now try to query for all objects that indeed have this key but not with the specific value `bar`. For this I use the following query:

```
collection.find({'foo': {'$exists': True}, 'foo': {'$ne': 'bar'}})
```

I thought that both criteria are connected via a logical AND. However, I get also objects that don't feature key `foo`. In fact, I get the same result when I just use the query

```
collection.find({'foo': {'$ne': 'bar'}})
```

On the other hans, if I use

```
collection.find({'foo': {'$exists': True}})
```

I correctly only get objects with `foo` but obvisouly all of them, so some of them have the value `bar`.

How do I have to formulate my query to achieve my initial result? Is there a kind of order in which multiple criteria are tested? Do I explicitly specify the logical AND of both criteria?

Comment: This is a great example of a basic pymongo query. I wish it came up earlier when I googled "pymongo find examples" :-\ . +1

Comment: I don't think there's need for specific examples for PyMongo since the syntax is essentially the same as when using the Mongo shell. I _think_ the Mongo shell is a bit more generous when it comes to having quotes around keywords and field names(e.g., `{$ne : 'bar'}` should work as well as  `{'$ne' : 'bar'}`). Maybe the capitalization of, e.g., `True` might matter also.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `$and` to join multiple conditions:

```
collection.find({"$and": [{"foo": {'$ne': 'bar'}}, 
                          {"foo": {'$exists': True}}]})
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just thought that if you have a list of criteria, `AND` is the implicitly given way to test them. Most example I found focused only on `$or`, hence perhaps my misconception. But to support arbitrary complex conditions, and `$and` is of course very meaningful.

Comment: shorter version for general uses `{"$and": [{"key1": value1}, {"key2": value2}]}`

Answer (score 20):

No necessary to use `$and`, it also works

```
db.collection.find({"foo":{"$ne":"bar", "$exists":true}})
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! So I guess I have this issue since both criterea refer to the same key `foo`. Is there any difference regarding the performance between both solutions?

Comment: making use of "$and" will return the entire document (say it returns just one result), whereas querying without "$and" will return only the resulting document id .